# Why does the google sheets ARRAYFUNCTION round my decimal to the nearest full number?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I wrote a function to calculate the number of working hours, expressed in workdays between 2 dates.  It returns a decimal.  However, when I surround the function with ARRAYFUNCTION(function goes here), it rounds all the decimals to the nearest full number.  Here is the formula, Both Q and O are datetimes:

```
=((NETWORKDAYS(Q2:Q, O2:O)-2) *(8) + 
IF( AND(TIME(HOUR(Q2:Q), MINUTE(Q2:Q), SECOND(Q2:Q)) > TIME(9,0,0), TIME(HOUR(Q2:Q), MINUTE(Q2:Q), SECOND(Q2:Q)) < TIME(17,0,0)),
    HOUR(TEXT(TIME(17,0,0)-TIME(HOUR(Q2:Q), MINUTE(Q2:Q), SECOND(Q2:Q)), "h:mm:ss")) + MINUTE(TEXT(TIME(17,0,0)-TIME(HOUR(Q2:Q), MINUTE(Q2:Q), SECOND(Q2:Q)), "h:mm:ss"))/60 + SECOND(TEXT(TIME(17,0,0)-TIME(HOUR(Q2:Q), MINUTE(Q2:Q), SECOND(Q2:Q)), "h:mm:ss"))/3600, 
    IF( TIME(HOUR(Q2:Q), MINUTE(Q2:Q), SECOND(Q2:Q)) < TIME(9,0,0), 8, 0 ) ) + 
    IF( AND(TIME(HOUR(O2:O), MINUTE(O2:O), SECOND(O2:O)) > TIME(9,0,0), TIME(HOUR(O2:O), MINUTE(O2:O), SECOND(O2:O)) < TIME(17,0,0)),
        HOUR(TEXT(TIME(HOUR(O2:O), MINUTE(O2:O), SECOND(O2:O)) - TIME(9,0,0), "h:mm:ss")) + MINUTE(TEXT(TIME(HOUR(O2:O), MINUTE(O2:O), SECOND(O2:O)) - TIME(9,0,0), "h:mm:ss"))/60 + SECOND(TEXT(TIME(HOUR(O2:O), MINUTE(O2:O), SECOND(O2:O)) - TIME(9,0,0), "h:mm:ss"))/3600, 
        IF( TIME(HOUR(O2:O), MINUTE(O2:O), SECOND(O2:O)) > TIME(17,0,0), 8,0 ) 
  )
)/8
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Also, apart from the difference in (working) days, is the second part of the formula calculating what fraction of each date is between 9 and 5, ie. working hours?

Comment: I'm not clear what your datetime values are like - I'm now getting decimal results for the array formula - here is a sample sheet:  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1huzMOMXEx_wih2SM3-bfBzRYn5U-e-4mskTf1I2Keqk/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I haven't fully gone through the math in your formula, and at first glance it seems reasonable.  Maybe I've made a mistake somewhere, but the fact that I don't see the same resuslts for the ArrayFormula as for the exact same formula dragged down seems to indicate something funny is going on.  As player0 asked, it would really help to have a sample sheet from you with your test dates.